# Is there a way to hide the unread count badge in El Capitan depending on the time of the day?

Tags: mail.app, email, macos, notifications

I know how to turn off the unread count badge for the mail icon using the `Notifications` preference pane from `system preferences` but I would like to know if it is possible to have it turned off for example from 8 in the morning until 17 and otherwise on?

I don't want to be disturbed by email during the day but I want to be reminded at the end of the day or at the beginning.

Comment: There is an option in Do Not Disturb to set the time, but unfortunately only for banners and alerts to be hidden. I would love to see this too as I don’t see the point in turning off _some_ of the notifications.

Comment: Completely agree with you.